# jQuery UI Tabs 3 and history plug-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using Tabs as follows:

```
<div id='tabs'>
  <ul>
    <li><a class='tab' href="#tabs_company_info">Company Info</a></li>
    <li><a class='tab' href="#tabs_contact">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a class='tab' href="#tabs_products">Products</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='tabs_company_info'>
... 
</div>
<div id='tabs_contact'>
    ... 
</div>
<div id='tabs_products'>
    ... 
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript: The same JavaScript as in the source of the [mikage.to](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html) page.

When I mouseover the links I see the #value appended to it, and when I click the tabs the URL changes. But when I use the browser's back button, the tabs don't change.

When the page loads with a hash value in the URL the following JavaScript is run

```
$("#load").load(hash + ".html");
```

But that doesn't preselect a tab ... ?

Comment: hi stef,
i believe it would be best if you supply the whole related sourcecode... otherwise it's more a guess what might be wrong...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#load").load(hash + ".html");
```

This loads appropriate page into the placeholder(`<div id="load"></div>`).
See

- [1](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/1.html)
- [2](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/2.html)
- [3](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/3.html)

from the abovementioned [example](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html).